# Is $nu_n$ convergent $\Leftrightarrow (u_n)$ converges to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to tell wether or not $nu_n$ is convergent $\Leftrightarrow (u_n)$ converges to $0$.
I can't find any example where it would be false, but I don't know how to prove it either !

How can I prove it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$\not\Leftarrow$: $u_n = \frac {{(-1)}^{n}} n$

$\Rightarrow$: try to prove that pointwise product of bounded sequence with convergent to zero sequence converges to $0$. Just use definition of convergence: $\{u_i\}$ converges to $v$ means that for every $\epsilon$ only finitely many $u_i$'s lie outside $(v - \epsilon, v+\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 0):

$ n\cdot u_n = \sum_{k=1}^n u_n $ converges and if a series converges $\implies$ it's general term $u_n$ converges to $0$

so the f̶i̶r̶s̶t̶ ̶i̶m̶p̶l̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶r̶u̶e̶. (I'm sorry no it isn't please read the comments below)

for the second implication you just need to consider the sequence $u_n =\frac{\ln n}{n}$ as a counterexample

$u_n \to 0$ but $n\cdot u_n = \ln n \to +\infty$

Comment: How do you conclude for the first impication?

Comment: let $S_n = n\cdot u_n = \sum_{k=1}^n u_n $,

$S_n$ converges $\implies \exists \ell \in \mathbb{R} | \lim_{n\to\infty}S_n = \ell$


observe that $u_n = S_{n+1}-S_n \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}S_{n+1}-\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n = \ell - \ell = 0 $

Comment: Why $n\cdot u_n = \sum_{k=1}^n u_n$? What is $u_n$ here?

Comment: $n\cdot u_n = (1+1+1+....+1)\cdot u_n = u_n+u_n+u_n+.....+u_n$ and there's $n$ terms exactly which means you can write that $n\cdot u_n= \sum_{k=1}^n u_n$

I don't get your second question though can you be clearer ?

Comment: I'm aware that you would like to construct a convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty v_n$. To do this, you should specify the $n$-term of this series. Could you give this general form of $v_n$ from the initial sequence $(u_n)_n$?

Comment: this ? : $v_n =  \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} u_k - \sum_{k=1}^{n} u_k $

Comment: Ok, as you said, $v_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}u_k - \sum_{k=1}^n u_k$ and it is exactly $v_n = u_{n+1}$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^n v_k  = u_2 + u_3 +\cdots u_{n+1} \neq n\cdot u_n$. Are you aware this?

Comment: I see where's my mistake when I made the assumption that $\sum_{k=1}^n u_n$ converges I can conclude that $\lim_{\color{red}{k}\to\infty}u_n =0 $ (which is doesn't make sense lol )not $\lim_{\color{red}{n}\to\infty}u_n =0 $
thanks for noticing gonna edit my post now

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion that $u_n \to 0$ but $nu_n \nrightarrow 0$ was shown by @xsln or @1.2.3. 
For the converse implication. Assume that $u_n \nrightarrow 0$, then $\limsup_n |u_n| :=a \in (0, \infty]$. We take a sub-sequence $(u_{n_k})_k$ such that $u_{n_k}\to a$ as $k\to \infty$. However in this case $n_k u_{n_k} \to \infty$ and this is a contradiction to the assumption $nu_n$ converges. Hence, $a=0$ and $u_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.